# Is it possible to add data when posting with ajax in tabulator5?

Tags: codeigniter, tabulator

I am using codeigniter4.
In the current environment, the csrf token must be included in the post data when making an ajax request.
I understand adding get parameters, but is it possible to add post data?

```
    //Build Tabulator
    var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height: "311px",
        layout: "fitColumns",
        ajaxURL: "user/test/ajaxtest/",
        ajaxParams :{ key1 : "value1" , key2 : "value2" },
        ajaxType:"POST",
        progressiveLoad: "scroll",
        paginationSize: 20,
        placeholder: "No Data Set",
        columns: [{
                title: "Name",
                field: "name",
                sorter: "string",
                width: 200
            },
            {
                title: "Progress",
                field: "progress",
                sorter: "number",
                formatter: "progress"
            },
            {
                title: "Gender",
                field: "gender",
                sorter: "string"
            },
            {
                title: "Rating",
                field: "rating",
                formatter: "star",
                hozAlign: "center",
                width: 100
            },
            {
                title: "Favourite Color",
                field: "col",
                sorter: "string"
            },
            {
                title: "Date Of Birth",
                field: "dob",
                sorter: "date",
                hozAlign: "center"
            },
            {
                title: "Driver",
                field: "car",
                hozAlign: "center",
                formatter: "tickCross",
                sorter: "boolean"
            },
        ],
    });
```

Anyone know please.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ajaxRequestFunc` to do this.

Refer to the documentation [here](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/data#ajax-promise). Using this, you could process your ajax request however you would prefer and just return the data to the table.

You could raise a POST request with params in your custom ajax call using `ajaxRequestFunc`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was able to solve it using ajaxRequestFunc. thank you!